# Should I be able to join other teams via SO Teams?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

I noticed while playing with the URL for Stack Overflow Teams I could easily try to join **other private teams**. I was able to apply to join the Fog Creek team and saw the ability to join several others. I know you still need an @teamEmailAddress.com to actually log into the team but this could be compromised as well.

Should the URL be obfuscated in a way such that it makes this not so trivial?

Comment: I'm tempted to think that this is a bug...

Comment: @Makoto - Dunno just asking.

Comment: From the title I thought that job ads were appearing within teams. (maybe they do, I'm not part of it...)

Comment: They don't, @mbrig. Teams looks like it's supposed to be self-supporting, not ad-rev-supported. Which makes sense, showing hiring ads to employees would dissuade employers from purchasing Teams

Comment: @undo Indeed, which is why I thought this may have been a slightly pun-y bug report :)

Answer (score 17):

> Should I be able to join other teams via SO Teams?

Nope, you shouldn't, unless you are who they've allowed to do so. But that's not what's happening in this question. You're really asking should you be able to ***try*** joining other teams. It depends on the team settings (controlled by the admin).

Teams has 2 joining style options: they can allow anyone in their organization (via email domain) to join (user self-serve style), or they can disable this and only allow per-user invites sent by an admin. For teams that are set to allow email domain, yes, they are intentionally **discoverable**, but you cannot join them without a valid email.

In the domain model, you must control and validate an email at that domain to proceed with joining a team. In an invite model you must also demonstrate control of the email it was sent to. In either case, you have to be who you claim to be.

Comment: self-serve style _can_ be vulnerable to things similar to what is described [here](https://medium.com/intigriti/how-i-hacked-hundreds-of-companies-through-their-helpdesk-b7680ddc2d4c). Does the admin get notified of new users in the self-serve model?

Comment: @gomory-chvatal we do log that it happened, it's not admin visible yet

Comment: Should be invite only. Not easily discoverable.

Comment: @JonH An admin can make that decision if they choose. However, it's up to them, not you.